# What design pattern can I use for manipulating controller params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I'm trying to find the cleanest way to code a series of manipulations to controller params

My application has a use case where 2 running experiments are using the same controller to update a model. It's too complex to completely split out at this point so I'm just manipulating the controller params.

So the params need to go through N number of functions to update the different attributes and then return them. I'm trying to do this in the cleanest way possible as I'm still learning design pattern. was looking for some input on my approach and possible better patterns to solve this problem

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def update
       manipulated_params = ParamsManipulationService.call(params)
       user = User.update(manipulated_params)
    end
end

class ParamsManipulationService
   attr_reader :params
   def initialize(params:)
      @params = params
    end

  def call
      manipulate_params
  end

  private
  
  def manipulate_params
      manipulate_func_one(params).
        then { |params| manipulate_func_two(params) }.
        then { |params| manipulate_func_three(params)}
  end

  def manipulate_func_one(params)
   # return some manipulated params
  end

  def manipulate_func_two(params)
   # return some manipulated params
  end

  def manipulate_func_three(params)
   # return some manipulated params
  end
end

class ApplicationService
  def self.call(*args, **kwargs, &block)
    new(*args, **kwargs, &block).call
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on what those manipulate functions do? Do they add attributes, change attributes, or remove attributes from the params? What do they depend on? The current user, some parameter, an ENV variable?

Answer (score 1):

"too complex to completely split out at this point" should be a big red flag. "Too complex" means the code is brittle, difficult to maintain and difficult to test. My recommendation is to make sure that you have fantastic test coverage, and then refactor the code.

It's the most common Rails pattern to associate a single controller with a single model. But this is not necessary, and great simplification (maintainability/testability) can be achieved by associating controllers with workflows. For example, instead of UsersController, you might have AdminUsersController, ManagerUsersController, PublicUsersController etc., each of which has its own #update method, much simpler than your UsersController. They might even inherit from a common super class or have shared mixins. But they're all dealing with the same model. Moving the complexity off into a service object as you are suggesting doesn't reduce the complexity, it just moves it!

We can't see enough into your app to know if this is appropriate, but I recommend you find a way to eliminate the idea "too complex to split out at this point" from your app. Replace that dread of dealing with the complex code with sunny days and blue skies!